# Trying to make a month in a Calendar only used Nested Loops

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, nested

This is my code:

```
x = 8

while x <= 31:
    j = 1
    while j <= 7:
        print(j, "\t", end=' ')
        j += 1
    print("\n")
    print(x, "\t", end=' ')
    x += 7
```

The outcome is supposed to be where the month starts on a Sunday, starting from 1 - 31.

So far, this is the outcome of the code I have:

Sun      Mon     Tue     Wed     Thu     Fri     Sat

1         2       3       4       5       6      7

8         1       2       3       4       5       6       7

15        1       2       3       4       5       6       7

22        1       2       3       4       5       6       7

29

I can't figure out how to get the second line to continue with 9-14 and so on.

Comment: You actually can do it with a single loop, assuming that you already know what modulo (`%`) operator is.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new line on each 7th day

```
for x in range(1, 32):
    print(x, end = ' ')
    if x%7==0:
        print('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You were setting `j's` value to `1` on each loop and that is why you were getting 1 2 3... values repeated in each line. You can use this:

```
while days <= 31:
    print(days, "\t", end = ' ')
    if days % 7 == 0: # Checking if it's a week or not. If yes, then moving to new line.
        print('\n')
    days += 1
```

Output:

```
 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   

 8   9   10  11  12  13  14      

15   16  17  18  19  20  21      

22   23  24  25  26  27  28      

29   30  31
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number = eval(input("Enter a number between -6 and 2:\n"))

if -6<number<2:
    for i in range(number, number+41, 7):
        print("{:>2}".format(i))    # user use string formatting in place of space for purpose of two characters
        for j in range(number, number+7):
            print("{:>2}".format(i+j+5),sep=" ",end=" ") 
else:
    print("Invalid input! The value of 'n' should be between -6 and 2.")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).